# Android Type mismatch help. Convert ArrayList to List?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Ok.. this might be hard to follow..

App saves Contacts to a SQLite database named CONTACTS.

ContactActivity should load in the SQLite database and create a custom ListView that allows for the selection of multiple Contacts via a Toggle button.

The example I was following to create the custom LV allowing multiple selections has a local Contact class. I am running into problems converting from the external DAO Contact class to the local Contact class.

Contact.java DAO class:

```
package dto;

/**
 * This DTO describes a Contact that can create and respond to a Survey
 * @author Barnitek, Bosticsa
 *
 */

public class Contact {

private int id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String phoneNumber;

public Contact(){

}

public Contact(int id, String firstName, String lastName, String phoneNumber){
    this.id = id;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}

public Contact(String firstName, String lastName, String phoneNumber){
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}

public int getID(){
    return id;
}

public void setID(int id){
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
public String getPhoneNumber() {
    return phoneNumber;
}
public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}
}
```

The ContactActivity class:

```
package edu.uc.pollyo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import dao.PollyoBaseDAO;

/**
 * 
 * @author Barnitek
 * 
 *         This activity builds a custom list view that lists an array of names
 *         and phone numbers with checkable boxes. When a box is checks the
 *         name+number from that row is added to a string that will then be
 *         returned to the MainActivity and placed in the contacts text view.
 * 
 */

public class ContactActivity extends MainActivity {
private ListView mainListView;
private ArrayAdapter<Contact> listAdapter;
private List<Contact> contactList;
private ArrayList<dto.Contact> contactArrayList;

public static String listContacts = "";
PollyoBaseDAO mydb;


// when activity is created
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact);

    //contactList = new ArrayList<dto.Contact>();
    mydb = new PollyoBaseDAO(this);
    contactArrayList = mydb.getAllContacts();


    //**************PROBBLEM HERE***************
    // The problem is: Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<Contact> to
   //  List<ContactActivity.Contact>
    contactList = contactArrayList;

    // Set our custom array adapter as the ListView's adapter.
    listAdapter = new ContactArrayAdapter( getApplicationContext(), contactList);
    // Find the ListView resource.
    mainListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvContactView);
    mainListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    // When item is tapped, toggle checked properties of CheckBox and
    // Contact.
    mainListView
            .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View item,
                        int position, long id) {
                    Contact contact = listAdapter.getItem(position);
                    contact.toggleChecked();
                    ContactViewHolder viewHolder = (ContactViewHolder) item
                            .getTag();
                    viewHolder.getCheckBox()
                            .setChecked(contact.isChecked());

                    // build a string of selected contacts when one is
                    // checked
                    listContacts += contact.getFirstName() + " " + contact.getLastName() + " | ";
                    System.out.println("listContacts: (ContactActivity) "
                            + listContacts);

                }
            });

    mainListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}

// Holds contact data
private static class Contact {
    private String firstName = "";
    private String lastName = "";

    private boolean checked = false;

    public Contact(){};

    public Contact(String firstName, String lastName){
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public Contact (String firstName, String lastName, boolean checked){
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.checked = checked;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName(){
        return lastName;
    }

    public boolean isChecked() {
        return checked;
    }

    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        this.checked = checked;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void toggleChecked() {
        checked = !checked;
    }
}

// Holds child views for each row
private static class ContactViewHolder {
    private CheckBox checkBox;
    private TextView textView;

    public ContactViewHolder(){};

    public ContactViewHolder(TextView textView, CheckBox checkBox) {
        this.checkBox = checkBox;
        this.textView = textView;
    }

    public CheckBox getCheckBox() {
        return checkBox;
    }

    public TextView getTextView() {
        return textView;
    }

    public void setTextView(TextView textView){
        this.textView = textView;
    }
}

/** Custom adapter for displaying an array of Contact objects. */
private static class ContactArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contact> {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ContactArrayAdapter(Context context, List<Contact> contactList) {
        super(context, R.layout.simplerow, R.id.rowTextView, contactList);
        // Cache the LayoutInflate to avoid asking for a new one each time.
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // contact to display
        Contact contact = (Contact) this.getItem(position);

        // The child views in each row.
        CheckBox checkBox;
        TextView textView;

        // Create a new row view
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simplerow, parent);

            // Find the child views.
            textView = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.rowTextView);
            checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.CheckBox01);

            // Optimization: Tag the row with it's child views, so we don't
            // have to
            // call findViewById() later when we reuse the row.
            convertView.setTag(new ContactViewHolder(textView, checkBox));

            // If CheckBox is toggled, update the contact it is tagged with.
            checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                    Contact contact = (Contact) cb.getTag();
                    contact.setChecked(cb.isChecked());
                }
            });
        }
        // Reuse existing row view
        else {
            // Because we use a ViewHolder, we avoid having to call
            // findViewById().
            ContactViewHolder viewHolder = (ContactViewHolder) convertView
                    .getTag();
            checkBox = viewHolder.getCheckBox();
            textView = viewHolder.getTextView();
        }

        // Tag the CheckBox with the Contact it is displaying, so that we
        // can
        // access the contact in onClick() when the CheckBox is toggled.
        checkBox.setTag(contact);

        // Display contact data
        checkBox.setChecked(contact.isChecked());
        textView.setText(contact.getFirstName() + " " + contact.getLastName());

        return convertView;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.help:
        showHelp();
        return true;
    case R.id.about:
        showAbout();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

// launch the about activity
private void showAbout() {
    Intent about = new Intent(this, AboutActivity.class);
    startActivity(about);
}

// launch the help activity
private void showHelp() {
    Intent help = new Intent(this, HelpActivity.class);
    startActivity(help);
}

// when the user clicks OK, send the list of selected contacts back
public void onOkClicked(View v) {
    Intent output = new Intent();
    output.putExtra("selectedContacts", listContacts);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, output);
    finish();
}

// when the user clicks New Contact, start a new activity to add a new
// contact to the list
public void onNewContactClicked(View v) {
    Intent newContact = new Intent(this, AddContactActivity.class);
    startActivity(newContact);

}
}
```

The getAllContacts() method, incase it is needed:

```
public ArrayList<Contact> getAllContacts()
       {
          ArrayList<Contact> array_list = new ArrayList<Contact>();

          String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + CONTACTS;

          SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

          Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( selectQuery, null );

          if (res.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    Contact contact = new Contact();
                    contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(res.getString(0)));
                    contact.setFirstName(res.getString(1));
                    contact.setLastName(res.getString(2));
                    contact.setPhoneNumber(res.getString(3));
                    // Adding contact to list
                    array_list.add(contact);
                } while (res.moveToNext());
            }

            // return contact list
            return array_list;
       }
```

Does anyone have an idea on a way to do this? Or an easier way to read in a SQLite database and select multiple objects from it?

Comment: What kind of error do you see?

Comment: It's a Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<Contact> to List<ContactActivity.Contact> in the ContactActivity

Comment: Seems that you have an inner class ContactActivity.Contact within ContactActivity. That's causing the conflict.

Comment: Yes - that is the issue. We need to convert the ArrayList of type dao.Contact to the local type ContactAcvtivity.Contact..just not sure how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to write a method in you ContactActivity which looks like this:

I wrote dto.Contact and ContactActiviy.Contact to make clear, which one is which

```
private List<ContactActivity.Contact> transformListFromDB(List<dto.Contact> listFromDb) {
    List<ContactActivity.Contact> result = new ArrayList<ContactActivity.Contact>();
    for (dto.Contact con : listFromDb) {
         result.add(new ContactActivity.Contact(con.firstName, con.lastName); 
    }
    return result;
}
```

Then use: contactList = transformListFromDB(contactArrayList);

Comment: transformListFromDB seems to be a c# method? Not finding much about it in Java.. Can you elaborate?

Comment: see edit, you have to write that msg yourself! You won't find something like this in any lib

Comment: THANK YOU. I would upvote, however my rep isn't at 15 yet. Thanks for the help